# Can't seem to filter uniswap transactions?

Tags: uniswap, web3.py, brownie

The following code doesn't print any transactions. What am I missing?

```
def main():
  uni_v3_router = Web3.toChecksumAddress('0x68b3465833fb72a70ecdf485e0e4c7bd8665fc45')
  event_filter = w3.eth.filter({"address": uni_v3_router, 'fromBlock':'latest'})
  while True:
      print("checking for txn")
      for res in event_filter.get_new_entries():
          print(Web3.toJSON(res))
      time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb. I believe I just misunderstood what the address filter was referring to. The contract itself makes no transactions so this filter would always return nothing. What I needed was to just get all transactions in a block and then see if the "to" field was pointing at the uniswap v3 contract.